# Error: Unable to access jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar errorlevel=1 in

Tags: windows-7, jmeter, installation

How are you all ?? and Im doing good. !

Comment: Which version you have downloaded i.e Source or Binary. If it is binary then issue is something else. Download apache-jmeter-4.0.zip from the official site.

Comment: hard to say anything with so little information. Which version of JMeter? where did you unzip it? is error really cut at `errorlevel=1 in` or is there anything else?

Comment: Yes  i have downloaded wrong file,but i  downloaded new file (apache-jmeter-4.0.zip
http://www-eu.apache.org/dist//jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-4.0.zip)

 now its working fine guys thank you all

Comment: @sachin_ur if it helped you can accept the answer,see stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download the binary version for windows instead of Source.
Download apache-jmeter-4.0.zip from the official site.

Comment: what is the best tools to copy paste curl from browser to testapp and create our scenario like jmeter? this is very easy. is there any app better than jmeter?